# Использование функций из другого класса

Tags: python, kivy

Всем привет, хочу собрать небольшую программу с помощью  python и kivy. Есть два класса:1- сам скрипт
2- киви виджеты
Мне необходимо в переменную первого класса задать TextInput. То есть, переменная первого класса будет равна тому, что ввёл поьзователь
Вот небольшой набросок:

```
class x:
    def main(self):
        a = self.usertext.text # тут PyCharm ругается
class y(App,x):
    def build(self):
        self.usertext = TextInput(size_hint = (None,None),
                              size=(680,50))
```

Answer (score -1):

Вот так:

```
class x(object):
    ...
```

Comment: И что это   даст?

Comment: Ответ на вопрос это даст.

Comment: Как явное наследование от `object` решает проблему?